# Sigma.js : Assocaiative Color and Icon properties of new nodes not shown in graph

Tags: javascript, neo4j, sigma.js, linkurious

I got an example code from http://localhost:8000/examples/. And starting building my own. The problem that I am facing is that I have JSON of nodes from neo4j graph DB. that I want to add. I am succesful in adding it but the Icon and Color associated with the noe4j_labels are not represented in the graph.

Sigma Design Plugin is being used

```
var graphStyles = {
        nodes: {
            icon: {
                by: 'neo4j_labels',
                scheme: 'nodeIconScheme',
            },
            color: {
                by: 'neo4j_labels',
                scheme: 'nodeColorScheme',
            },
        }
    }

// Instanciate the design:
var design = sigma.plugins.design(s, {
    styles: graphStyles,
    palette: graphPalettes
});
```

The nodes that are added from the first query are represented properly with their respective Icons and Colors.

```
sigma.neo4j.cypher(
                { url: 'http://localhost:7474', user: 'neo4j', password: 'neo' },
                query_init,
                s,
                function(s) {
```

But when I try to add new nodes I run into this problem. 
`s.graph.addNode(new_graph_vars[0]);`

new_graph_vars has got JSON of various nodes

Object

```
0
:
Object
color
:
"#ff0000"
fa2_x
:
6.330295085906982
fa2_y
:
6.543041706085205
id
:
"148655"
label
:
"Desaru Investments (Cayman Isl.) Limited"
neo4j_data
:
Object
neo4j_labels
:
Object
read_cam0:size
:
1
read_cam0:x
:
6.330295085906982
read_cam0:y
:
6.543041706085205
renderer1:size
:
6.5694811875994725
renderer1:x
:
718.2437463015784
renderer1:y
:
651.9931886710822
size
:
1
x
:
6.330295085906982
y
:
6.543041706085205
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
9
__proto__
:
Array[0]
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't see the problem with `new_graph_vars` ... where this variable comes from ?
When you use the addNode function, do you see your new node ?

Comment: The object shown is contained in the new graph vars. I first run a query through sigma_neo4j_cypher plugin. A graph is diplayed after which i add nodes to it by adding for example the above object. This shows the node after sigmaInst.refresh but there is no color or icon on the graph. I think graph.display() is not working correctly .

Please note the graph was displayed correctly with colors and icons the first time.

Comment: Can you try to invoke this code after adding new nodes : 
design.deprecate();
design.apply();

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks